# using .net to a wrap a glass cylinder/tube around a 2d image

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics

I need find a way (in .net code) to create the effect of wrapping glass tube around a 2d image.  More or less like viewing a picture of a ship inside a glass bottle.

I've done a lot of searching for examples, and have even tried chatgpt to give me some ideas but have come up empty.

The 2d image I have, the glass tube around it is the challenge.

Any help/examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification's sake.  Are you sure you mean a 2D image and not a 3d?  As for the question, probably need to explain a bit more.  What is this 2d image, how are you loading it and wat info do you gave in the way of reference points?  Are you looking to draw this cylinder or load a transparent image? What have you attempted so far?  All in all, as is your question is probably far to board to be answered

Comment: The image is the screen of a Nixie Tube.  It is a 2D (width and height) image, like a regular photo.   On the 2D image I have already generated the Nixie Tube back screen, the characters to be displayed on it, and the wired mesh that goes in front.  However, its the glass tube effect that surrounds it that I am having  trouble with.  I have tried various approaches for applying transformations and opacity settings to the image (as suggested by chatgpt) using system.drawing.graphics but have been getting nowhere.  If you feel you can help that would be great.

Comment: if anyone ever stumbles on this post, i never really figured this out fully - but did make some inroads regarding shaping and lighting that may be of help to you and which can be found in this code: https://github.com/roblatour/NixieTubes/tree/main/extras/NixieTubeMaker